# Bootstrap 4.6.1 Carousel showing all carousel-items at once, despite only one item being active

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've been attempting to create a MySQLi recoredset driven Boostrap carousel but no matter what I do, all of the slides display at once despite only one item being active on load.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="128" class="active"></li>
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="182"></li>
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="201"></li>
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="202"></li>
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="203"></li>
            
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="205"></li>
                    
        </ol>
        
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            
          <div class="carousel-item slide128 active">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>What is The Vault Arts Centre?</h1>
                <p>Unoccupied and boarded up since 2017, Scottish charity Trad Music Trust developed this former bank premises into one of the region&#x27;s most exciting new live music and performing arts venues.</p>
                                    <p><a href="about_the_vault_arts_centre.php" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">About</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
          <div class="carousel-item slide182">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>Venue Hire</h1>
                <p>The Vault Arts Centre is perfectly located in the heart of Newton Stewart, has modern facilities including bar and staff and is fully wheelchair accessible.</p>
                                    <p><a href="venue_hire_newton_stewart.php" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Options & Pricing</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
          <div class="carousel-item slide201">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>Spring Grass Festival - Cup O&#x27; Joe +Support</h1>
                <p>Outstanding traditional bluegrass&#x2F;americana&#x2F;folk in May 2022 with Cup O&#x27; Joe, part of the inaugural Spring Grass Festival.  Saturday tickets on sale now.</p>
                                    <p><a href="https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk&#x2F;event_info.php?eID=217" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Info & Booking</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
          <div class="carousel-item slide202">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>Sabbra Cadabra</h1>
                <p>THE Black Sabbath Tribute Band return to The Vault Arts Centre on Saturday 5th February 2022 to perform the classic album Paranoid in full!  Tickets on sale now.</p>
                                    <p><a href="event_info.php?eID=221" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Book Online</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
          <div class="carousel-item slide203">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>Lords of Ruin +Reiver</h1>
                <p>North of England heavy rockers Lords of Ruin hit their debut at The Vault on Saturday 5th March 2022 with support from Reiver.</p>
                                    <p><a href="event_info.php?eID=222" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Book Online</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        
          <div class="carousel-item slide205">

            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>The Jaywalkers</h1>
                <p>The Jaywalkers perform live at this year&#x27;s SpringGrass bluegrass festival over 13th-15th May 2022.  Tickets on sale NOW!</p>
                                    <p><a href="https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk&#x2F;event_info.php?eID=229" class="btn btn-outline-light" role="button">Info & Booking</a></p>
                                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>

                
        </div>
        
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

The CSS is as follows....

```
    /* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
    width: 5%;
}

.slide128 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/DSCF0923banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                .slide182 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/DSCF1038banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                .slide201 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/IMG_0380banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                .slide202 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/RebelRockPhotography10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                .slide203 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/LordsofRuinBanner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                .slide205 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/768/Promo-5banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;   
          }
                  
    
        @media (min-width:992px){
                                .slide128 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/DSCF0923banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide182 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/DSCF1038banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide201 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/IMG_0380banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide202 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/RebelRockPhotography10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide203 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/LordsofRuinBanner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide205 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/992/Promo-5banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
            
        }
        
        @media (min-width:1200px){
                                .slide128 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/DSCF0923banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide182 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/DSCF1038banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide201 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/IMG_0380banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide202 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/RebelRockPhotography10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide203 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/LordsofRuinBanner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide205 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/1200/Promo-5banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
            
        }
    
        @media (min-width:1366px){
                                .slide128 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/DSCF0923banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide182 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/DSCF1038banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide201 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/IMG_0380banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide202 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/RebelRockPhotography10.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide203 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/LordsofRuinBanner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
                    .slide205 {
            background: url(https://www.thevaultartscentre.co.uk/img/Promo-5banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
        background-attachment:scroll;
            }
            
        }
```

I've set this up on JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/j9k2uLr3/4/) and was pleased to see that the same problem is occuring.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. All the items stack up on each other because of your CSS:

Change

```
.carousel-item {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   height: 300px;
}
```

to

```
.carousel-item {
   height: 300px;
}
```

If you block all `carousel-item`, then they will persist themselves on the screen, hence the stack. Also you don't need both `height`, only the last one will work. So remove the `height: 100%;`.

2. There is an issue with your CDNs. You are importing `bootstrap.bundle.js` and also `popper.js`. Bootstrap Bundle already has popper in it, so it conflicts. Remove the `popper.js` import.

Make these two changes, and your carousel should work normally.